# What is Ember Data's expected response for JsonApiSerializer + EmbeddedRecordsMixin

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, json-api

How should the response from the server look when doing a POST to create new records or a PATCH to update existing records, using the default `JsonApiSerializer and Adapter` but combined with the `DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin`, to include a `hasMany` relationship in the request.

This is important as Ember Data uses the response to assign Id's to records after being created, and change their state.

Consider the following request, where an Invoice is created in combination with 2 invoice lines.

```
{
    "data": {
        "type": "sales-invoices",
        "attributes": {
            "name": null,
            "net-price": 29,
            "vat-amount": 6.09,
            "gross-price": 35.09
        },
        "relationships": {
            "customer": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "companies",
                    "id": "131"
                }
            },
            "organization": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "organizations",
                    "id": "3"
                }
            }
        },
        "sales-invoice-lines": [
            {
                "data": {
                    "attributes": {
                        "name": "Basic Linux Hosting",
                        "sort": 0,
                        "unit-price": 9,
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "total": 9,
                        "net-price": 9,
                        "vat-amount": 1.89,
                        "gross-price": 10.89,
                        "created": null,
                        "changed": null
                    },
                    "relationships": {
                        "sales-invoice": {
                            "data": {
                                "type": "sales-invoices",
                                "id": null
                            }
                        },
                        "vat-rate": {
                            "data": {
                                "type": "vat-rates",
                                "id": "1"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "type": "sales-invoice-lines"
                }
            },
            {
                "data": {
                    "attributes": {
                        "name": "Extra .com domain",
                        "sort": 1,
                        "unit-price": 20,
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "total": 20,
                        "net-price": 20,
                        "vat-amount": 4.2,
                        "gross-price": 24.2,
                        "created": null,
                        "changed": null
                    },
                    "relationships": {
                        "sales-invoice": {
                            "data": {
                                "type": "sales-invoices",
                                "id": null
                            }
                        },
                        "vat-rate": {
                            "data": {
                                "type": "vat-rates",
                                "id": "1"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "type": "sales-invoice-lines"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

In a normal GET request, [Json Api](http://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-includes) includes the separate invoice lines in the `included` hash (see link for specification). 
For the Embedded Records, should the response from the POST or PATCH include the records in the included hash, or in the (in this case) sales-invoice-lines hash?

- Does any of this even work with Ember data?
- Are the records in the store updated with the response we get from the server?
- Are the id's assigned?
- How are the id's assigned? Based on the order in the array?

Comment: I use jsonapiserializer and I use the include attribute. If you have that model defined for the included data, ember recognizes it and inserts the data into the store. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: No, if I do a post, where I create an invoice together with invoice lines, before doing the post I already have (in this case 3, invoice + 2 invoice lines) models in my store; When getting a response, I want to match the Ids of the invoice and the 2 invoice lines with the models already in the store. How does this work with EmbeddedRecordsMixin?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid EmbeddedRecord isn't supported when using JSONAPIAdapter/Serializer. You'll need to do your embedded payload via the included hash instead.

Comment: Can you please elaborate this. I don't understand my jsonapiserializer does not include associations